# How to fix Flutter test from sdk is incompatible with flutter from sdk?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I cannot see vector_math as a package but still flutter is giving me this error

"Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on vector_math 2.1.2 and every version of flutter from sdk depends on vector_math 2.1.4, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with flutter from sdk."

How to deal with this issue ?

My Pubspec is like below

```
dependencies:


flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  flutter_otp_text_field: ^1.1.1
  page_transition: ^2.0.9
  flutter_displaymode: ^0.5.0
  table_calendar: ^3.0.8
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.1.1
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  geocoding: ^2.0.5
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  dio: ^4.0.6
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.7.0
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1
  image: ^4.0.15
  in_app_update: ^4.0.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.13
  path: ^1.8.0
  qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1
  flutter_speed_dial: ^6.2.0
  dropdown_search: ^3.0.1
  multi_image_picker: ^4.8.01
  camera: ^0.10.3+2
  get: ^4.6.5
  intl: ^0.18.0
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.0.5
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.12.0
  location: ^4.4.0
  platform_device_id: ^1.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.10

dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.5.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  beacons_plugin: ^2.0.8
  #device_info: ^1.0.0
  device_info_plus: ^8.1.0
  csv: ^5.0.1
  http: ^0.13.0
  flutter_archive: ^5.0.0
  web_socket_channel: ^2.3.0
  flutter_downloader: ^1.7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the following command to update the package dependencies in your local instance of the Flutter SDK ([source](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#updating-package-dependencies)).

```
flutter update-packages --force-upgrade
```

If you navigate to where you installed Flutter and locate the pubspec.yaml file at flutter -> packages -> flutter -> pubspec.yaml, you'll see this in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter pub deps`. Probably one of your dependencies rely on this package. This way you can identify which one.

Comment: Not working its still showing the same error 
"Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on vector_math 2.1.2 and every version of flutter from sdk depends on vector_math 2.1.4, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with flutter from sdk."

Comment: Yes, this command will allow you to check the dependencies and try to identify whats wrong. I don't have enough information from your question to give you a better answer.

Comment: I am running that command but at first only this vector_math error is coming

Comment: Can you add this info on the question?

Comment: flutter_test is giving me problems such as 
"The getter 'configuration' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformDispatcher'"